# Time complexity of finding nullspace of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

The problem is finding the nullspace of a singular $n \times n$ square matrix $A$
(or alternatively computing the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue 0).

What is the algorithm with the lowest time complexity of finding the nullspace.

e.g. for SVD this is $O(n^3)$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're definitely going to need a rank-revealing factorization, like RRQR or RRLU. A straight QR or LU will not accomplish this; you need a column pivoting strategy. The literature is diverse on this topic, and I'll be honest I don't know which algorithm is considered the best at this point---perhaps because there is not a consensus!

For a complexity measure, I'll offer one example from "Rank Revealing QR Factorizations" by Tony F. Chan, Yale University, 1985 [(PDF here)](http://www.cs.yale.edu/publications/techreports/tr398.pdf). The algorithm he presents achieves a complexity of $2n^3/3+4n^2r$ flops, where $r$ is the rank. In contrast, he quotes a complexity of $6n^3$ for the SVD.

EDIT: I was thinking about this more, and I believe that the TRP variant of [LUSOL](http://www.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/lusol.html) is likely to be one of the more efficient *readily-available* algorithms out there. Do note however that it is designed for sparse matrices.

For dense matrices, I suspect [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379500001208) comes close to providing the best choice, a rank-revealing LU factorization. [Here](http://math.berkeley.edu/~luiza/RRLU.pdf) is a paper that builds upon the work of Pan but is freely available.

Finally, note the theoretical complexity bound of LU factorization matches that of matrix multiplication. Hence there exist, in theory, methods for LU factorization that achieve, say, $O(n^{2.5})$ complexity and better. Whether anyone has actually used one in an RRLU setting I do not know (but I doubt).

Comment: Thank you Michael. I'll wait for further comments.

Comment: Added a couple more thoughts here. I'm not expecting a bounty (indeed I don't think you had one when I first answered).

Comment: Wouldn’t Gaussian elimination reveal the kernel of a matrix as well? What complexity would that be?

Comment: @gen Gaussian Elimination is at the core of the LU factorization. But proper pivoting strategies are necessary to ensure that the factorization is accurate enough to be rank revealing.